# Jquery parse string for symbols, start at "(", end at ")"

Tags: jquery, regex

So what I'm trying to do is figure out any possible ways to make jquery look through specific string for symbols between brackets () and return them. For example, here is the HTML:

```
<div class="someblock">Text to look through (251).</div>
```

End result must be "(251)". Any ways to do that?

Comment: If you need how to do, then simply use jQuery(".someblock").html() in a variable and than use regular expression to extract the number. If you need written solution then let us know !!!

Comment: What are all possible cases ? Can multiple symbols be the same string like `some text (33) other text (55)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery and Regex:

```
$('.someblock').html().match(/(\(\w+\))/gi);
```

Gives you an array of matches. If it's only supposed to search for numbers:

```
.match(/(\(\d+\))/g);
```

Comment: i modifier is useless in the latter exemple